# Grass 6.4.3 v.rast.stats: Calculate only one value

Tags: grass-gis

I am using the grass (6.4.3!) function `v.rast.stats` to calculate the mean value of rast values over polygons.

The tool is somewhat slow and I actually only need the mean value.
Is there any possibility/trick to reduce the calculation to the mean value (just like in grass 7.0)?

Comment: Any change to update to GRASS GIS 7? We released the stable 7 more than a year ago, after years of development... it is worth it! We have done major effort to make it faster, see https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.0.0-News

Comment: Thanks @markusN! I'm sure it's worth it...the problem is the script is really long and I fear it would be some effort to rewrite it to GRASS 7.0. But maybe it's really worth it!

Comment: We have documented all changes, so it may be a reasonably small job for you: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.0.0-News#Optionchanges:flagsandparametersharmonized (and further down on that page). In case of doubts, just ask :)

Comment: Ah, cool!!!!! I didn't know that this list exists! Then it's really nice and easy! Thanks a lot for your help!!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, maybe the simplest option would just be to update to GRASS 7.0 with the help of the list mentioned by @markusN:

https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.0.0-News#Optionchanges:flagsandparametersharmonized

Answer (score 3):

From the [doc](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.rast.stats.html), I don't think it's possible.

However, if you are free to use QGIS, you could give a try to the [LecoS](https://conservationecology.wordpress.com/qgis-plugins-and-scripts/lecos-land-cover-statistics/) plugin which allows you to choose the metric you want to compute (contrary to the native zonal statistics plugin).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, when inspecting the source code I found out that GRASS 6.4.3's `v.rast.stats` grasps the output from `r.univar` with the bash command `cut -d | -f`.

As `r.univar` itself is a compiled script already and all statistics are calculated anyway, there is few possibility to get the script faster as far as I see things. The only way is to reduce the number of columns added to the attribute table in `v.rats.stats`, but with respect to time this will make only a small difference.